# Using greater than and Less than or if statments

Tags: python, comparison

The problem I have with this, a warning sign keeps on coming up 
intended block.

Python 2

```
input = raw_input("Please enter an integer:  ")

A = int(input)

if A > 10 -24:

if A < 0 + 24:

print (A)
```

Comment: What do you intend to do here?

Comment: I am writing a program in python to calculate sidereal time.

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your intention was to check whether `A` was in the range (-14, 24).

For that purpose, you should not use two conditionals on the same indentation level, but rather a nested if:

```
if A > -14:
    if A < 24:
        print(A)
```

A better syntax for that specific case would use `and` on a single `if` statement:

```
if A > -14 and A < 24:
    print(A)
```

And the best scenario would be leveraging python's expanding comparisons:

```
if -14 < A < 24:
    print(A)
```

Or leveraging the `range` function and the `contains` operator:

```
if A in range(-14, 24):
    print(A)
```

Comment: Thank you this has been a great help.